# How to update when column A is null and Column B is null then have to update with previous record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table :

| ID | ID1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | NULL |
| 1 | 2 |
| NULL | 1 |
| 3 | NULL |
| NULL | 6 |

Desired output:

| ID | ID1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 6 |

Comment: "previous" requires that there be some kind of **ordering** - what are your rows ordered by??

Comment: in order by (select (0))

Comment: So any arbitrary row, @Avinashc ? As that's what `(ORDER BY (SELECT 0))` means. If the prior arbitrary row also has the value `NULL` is updating the value will `NULL` ok?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lag` to get the value of the previous row in a cte then update the cte:

```
with u as
(select ID,
ID1, 
lag(ID) over(order by (select 0)) as prevID, 
lag(ID1) over(order by (select 0)) as prevID1
from table_name
)
update u
set u.ID = coalesce(u.ID, u.prevID), u.ID1 = coalesce(u.ID1, u.prevID1)
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b9745ce090883942300608170215a72e)

Comment: This is not guaranteed to update a previous row, it can update any row with no actual order specified.

Comment: @Stu That's not true, the *overall* order is arbitrary, but each row will have a specific position within it. It is not possible, for example, for all rows to get the same `lag` previous row.

Comment: Yes of course, that's not what I meant, in so far as what the OP is requesting, only each individual value obtained to update a specific row is not predetermined by repeatable criteria.